# C# windows form project Divide variable error

Tags: c#

Greeting everyone, I'm trying to do a windows form for collage were I can get the average of student scores. Seems like I have an issue with the divide function. here is my code , to see if you guys spot something wrong that could help me. I Appreciate in advance

```
    private void getaveragebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (customTextboxes4.Texts == "" || customTextboxes5.Texts == "" || customTextboxes6.Texts == "" || customTextboxes7.Texts == "" || customTextboxes8.Texts == "" ||
            customTextboxes9.Texts == "" || customTextboxes10.Texts == "" || customTextboxes11.Texts == "" || customTextboxes12.Texts == "" || customTextboxes13.Texts == ""
            || customTextboxes15.Texts == "" || customTextboxes16.Texts == "" || customTextboxes17.Texts == "" || customTextboxes18.Texts == "" || customTextboxes19.Texts == "" ||
            customTextboxes20.Texts == "" || customTextboxes21.Texts == "" || customTextboxes22.Texts == "" || customTextboxes23.Texts == "" || customTextboxes24.Texts == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill all the Boxes with Digits");
        }

        else
        {

            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            label61.Visible = true;
            label28.Visible = true;
            label29.Visible = true;
            label30.Visible = true;
            label31.Visible = true;
            label45.Visible = true;
            label46.Visible = true;


            //short--test calculations

            //students short test score variables
            decimal a, b, c, d, e1, f, g, h, i, j;
            //students short test value variables
            decimal k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t;
            //st results variables
            decimal u, v;
            decimal r1st;
            decimal r2st;
            decimal results;

            //customboxes st score
            a = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes4.Texts);
            b = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes5.Texts);
            c = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes6.Texts);
            d = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes7.Texts);
            e1 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes8.Texts);
            f = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes9.Texts);
            g = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes10.Texts);
            h = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes11.Texts);
            i = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes12.Texts);
            j = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes13.Texts);

            //custom boxes st values
            k = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes15.Texts);
            l = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes16.Texts);
            m = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes17.Texts);
            n = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes18.Texts);
            o = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes19.Texts);
            p = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes20.Texts);
            q = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes21.Texts);
            r = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes22.Texts);
            s = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes23.Texts);
            t = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes24.Texts);

            r1st = a + b + c + d + e1 + f + g + h + i + j;
            r2st = k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t;
            //st results variables definitions
            u = Decimal.Parse(label28.Text);
            v = Decimal.Parse(label29.Text);
           
           
            //st result



            label28.Text = r1st.ToString();
            label29.Text = r2st.ToString();
            results = u / v;
            label4.Text = results.ToString();
           
            return;
        }
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpSI0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu8cp.png)

Im trying to get all the score inserted in the text boxes to sum them. then get the results to Student Score and Total (That part is working for me) . After that divide the Student Score / Total to get the results in a hidden label that will be visible after getting the results. (that is the part that Im having issues with)

Comment: C# and C are unrelated languages except that their names share a common first (only) letter.  Do not use both language tags.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new to this forum, next time I will check everything to comply with the requirements to post correctly. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you used meaningful variable names. Just which divide are you having trouble with? Which variable is the Student Score and which is Total? If you want somebody to understand your code and provide suggestions, you should make it as easy as possible to understand. Also, what exact problem are you experiencing? You say you have a "divide variable error." Care to provide a bit more detail?

Comment: At the point where you calculate `v` by parsing `label29.Text`, this is still empty and `v` will not be initialized (and remain 0).
So when calculating `results`, you are dividing by zero. Move the assignments for label28 & 29  forward, just before parsing `u` and `v`

Comment: @JimMischel the code is to be part of a some *collage* - so I think it is artistic choice to use single-letter sequential names. I would probably use array (as usually fake code shown in movies / posters includes `for` loop and array would fit perfectly), but maybe for OP's purposes they need long stretches of similarly looking code?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Silly me. I thought he meant *college*. I suppose you're right. If I were writing code for a *collage*, I might make different choices.

Answer (score 2):

Well sorry to everyone for not following the proper way to post to get the proper help and thanks for those who let me know what to do for a next time to get the proper help. Also , thank you for explaining me the variable thing that was empty I really appreciate. Here is how I did fix my issue:

```
    private void getaveragebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (customTextboxes4.Texts == "" || customTextboxes5.Texts == "" || customTextboxes6.Texts == "" || customTextboxes7.Texts == "" || customTextboxes8.Texts == "" ||
            customTextboxes9.Texts == "" || customTextboxes10.Texts == "" || customTextboxes11.Texts == "" || customTextboxes12.Texts == "" || customTextboxes13.Texts == ""
            || customTextboxes15.Texts == "" || customTextboxes16.Texts == "" || customTextboxes17.Texts == "" || customTextboxes18.Texts == "" || customTextboxes19.Texts == "" ||
            customTextboxes20.Texts == "" || customTextboxes21.Texts == "" || customTextboxes22.Texts == "" || customTextboxes23.Texts == "" || customTextboxes24.Texts == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill all the Boxes with Digits");
        }

        else
        {

            label4.Visible = true;
            label5.Visible = true;
            label7.Visible = true;
            label61.Visible = true;
            label28.Visible = true;
            label29.Visible = true;
            label30.Visible = true;
            label31.Visible = true;
            label45.Visible = true;
            label46.Visible = true;


            //short--test calculations

            //students short test score variables
            decimal studentscorebox1, studentscorebox2, studentscorebox3, studentscorebox4, studentscorebox5, studentscorebox6, studentscorebox7, studentscorebox8, studentscorebox9, studentscorebox10;
            //students short test value variables
            decimal studentshorttestvalue1, studentshorttestvalue2, studentshorttestvalue3, studentshorttestvalue4, studentshorttestvalue5, studentshorttestvalue6, studentshorttestvalue7, studentshorttestvalue8,
                studentshorttestvalue9, studentshorttestvalue10;
            //st results variables
            
            decimal studentshortestoverallscore;
            decimal shortestoverallvalue;
            decimal shortestaverage;

            //customboxes student short test scores
            studentscorebox1 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes4.Texts);
            studentscorebox2 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes5.Texts);
            studentscorebox3 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes6.Texts);
            studentscorebox4 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes7.Texts);
            studentscorebox5 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes8.Texts);
            studentscorebox6 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes9.Texts);
            studentscorebox7 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes10.Texts);
            studentscorebox8 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes11.Texts);
            studentscorebox9 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes12.Texts);
            studentscorebox10 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes13.Texts);

            //student short test value
            studentshorttestvalue1 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes15.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue2 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes16.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue3 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes17.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue4 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes18.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue5 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes19.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue6 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes20.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue7 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes21.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue8 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes22.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue9 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes23.Texts);
            studentshorttestvalue10 = Decimal.Parse(customTextboxes24.Texts);

            //Sumatory of Students scores and Sumatory of Test Value
            studentshortestoverallscore = studentscorebox1 + studentscorebox2 + studentscorebox3 + studentscorebox4 + studentscorebox5 + studentscorebox6 + studentscorebox7 + studentscorebox8 + studentscorebox9 + studentscorebox10;
            shortestoverallvalue = studentshorttestvalue1 + studentshorttestvalue2 + studentshorttestvalue3 + studentshorttestvalue4 + studentshorttestvalue5 + studentshorttestvalue6 + studentshorttestvalue7 +
                studentshorttestvalue8 + studentshorttestvalue9 + studentshorttestvalue10;
          

            //String Results to Labels

            label28.Text = studentshortestoverallscore.ToString();
            label29.Text = shortestoverallvalue.ToString();
            //Get Average of Short Test
              shortestaverage = studentshortestoverallscore / shortestoverallvalue * 100;
              label4.Text = shortestaverage.ToString();

            return;
        }

    }
```

I did a correction of the variable names to not get confused like I was advised in the first post , then I deleted some variables that were empty like someone here explained me (thanks). Finally I did a re order of how it should be calculated to get the average and got it working. thanks to all and if you see something that I can improve let me know. I really appreciate everyone and every single advise. Have a good day everyone.

Comment: If you fixed your own question it's perfectly ok to accept your answer, fyi. Glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert label to decimal as long as label contains no value. You have to rearrange the lines as follows

```
        //st result

        label28.Text = r1st.ToString();
        label29.Text = r2st.ToString();

        u = Decimal.Parse(label28.Text);
        v = Decimal.Parse(label29.Text);

        results = u / v;
        label4.Text = results.ToString();
       
        return;
```